# fix loop to save essential windows processes, with its path, and kill the rest processes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I want to save the some system processes, **with its path**, to ensure that the system does not crash, and kill the rest of process

example: lsass.exe, winlogon.exe, conhost.exe, rundll32.exe, etc

This is my .bat:

```
set proc=,
:: proc
call:proc "lsass.exe"
call:proc "winlogon.exe"
call:proc "conhost.exe"
call:proc "rundll32.exe"

for /f "skip=3 tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /fi "username eq %username%"') do (
echo %proc%, | findstr /c:,%%a, 1>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
taskkill /f /im %%a /t
) else (
echo not kill
)
)

:: funcion proc
@echo off
pause
goto:eof
:proc
set getproc=%1
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%F in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %getproc%" /fo csv') do set proc=%proc%,%%~F>nul
goto:eof
```

The problem is that my script does not save the path of the process, then, if there is a fake process running in another location, my script saves both processes. That's why I need to save the Windows system process including its original path

Example real process:

```
wmic process where "name='lsass.exe'" get ExecutablePath
```

Out real process:

```
C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe
```

Example fake process:

Out XP:

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local settings\Application Data\lsass.exe
```

or Out 7

```
 C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\lsass.exe
 c:\Users\User\Local Setting\Temp\lsass.exe
 c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\lsass.exe
```

Note: Fake processes can be run from any path (.exe files associated with false process can be stored anywhere on the PC), except system folders (% windir%/system32 %windir%/sysWOW64 %windir%, etc)

Unfortunately, until now, My script does not close the fake processes, and only I could close manually using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)

**request:** What I need is to **save the real processes, with its original path** (lsass.exe, winlogon.exe, etc), **and kill the rest**. Thanks

Comment: You tell us that the processes are system but you are only filtering tasks belonging to the current user, that will ignore every 'System' process. You state that taskkill cannot kill them but you are using taskkill. You don't explain what a fake process is or what good processes are. We need a better explanation and probably all of the code you have kept from us.

Comment: Your question is now more clear.

Comment: @bdc Compo is right... In the code there are lines `call:process [...]` The program tries to jump to a nonexistent label and produces errors... If you are calling the label then there is code missing above. If not, your code will fail...

Comment: Provide us with your whitelist of every possible full path to every possible good process on every one of your possible target systems and update your question with this information.

Comment: Do NOT think that by killing processes that have the same image name as system processes but a different path, you're writing a functional antivirus or antimalware batch script. While this may be a fun exercise, it is NO replacement to installing proper virus and malware detection software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1141321/wmic-variables-path-and-folders/1141393), by [@JosefZ](https://superuser.com/users/376602/josefz)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

REM note double quotes                          REM added for debugging ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
set "_var="%userprofile%","%Appdata%","%HOMEPATH%","%homedrive%\ProgramData","D:\Remote""
                                                REM added for debugging ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

REM wmic requires double backslashes in specified path 
set "_var=%_var:\=\\%"

for %%G in  (%_var%) do (
rem echo processing %%G
  REM used `GET Caption` for debugging
rem WMIC PROCESS WHERE "Name = '%~1' and ExecutablePath Like '%%%%~G%%'" GET Caption

  REM operational 
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "Name = '%~1' and ExecutablePath Like '%%%%~G%%'" Call terminate 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try using WMIC directly.

```bat
@echo off
call :proc "lsass.exe"
call :proc "winlogon.exe"
call :proc "conhost.exe"
call :proc "rundll32.exe"
call :proc "services.exe
exit/b

:proc
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "Name='%~1' AND ExecutablePath Like '%%\\AppData\\%%'" CALL Terminate
```

**[Edit /]**
Because it is impossible to determine every single process which may or may not suit your purpose, the following, typed into the cmd prompt window, should close every single process which is not located within an exact path containing **\Windows\** or **\Program Files**. Use it at your own peril.

```bat
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "NOT ExecutablePath LIKE '%\\Windows\\%' AND NOT ExecutablePath LIKE '%\\Program Files%'" CALL TERMINATE
```

Comment: It would help if you were to provide some feedback…

Comment: I updated the question with the complete code, and real cases. I do not know what else you need

Comment: How does the code I've provided work in relation to the closure of the processes?

Comment: If you're trying to tell me that you are wanting to kill the processes not in \AppData\ and those processes are the ones in my code above then the answer is no. **I will not provide code that will render a PC unresponsive or that will allow some 'fake processes' to replace those genuine processes**. If that's not what you mean then you're going to once again have to make another edit to your question such that I can understand your problem better.

Comment: False processes can stay anywhere on the PC. Appdata is just a random example. I updated the question for you to have greater clarity, clarifying this part. I think there sufficient clarity in the question

Comment: You need to provide a real scenario for real help, your question still has no bearing on the information you're mentioning in your comments. You have edited your task so many times, and so much time has already been invested into helping you with your issue, that you at least owe it to this site to help us to help you.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you wanting to close? what are you wanting to save? what is your intention and end goal? I have updated my answer with an [Edit /] as my last attempt to provide you with something you can use.

Comment: this is not what i ask or what i'm looking for. Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: Explain it better then! _If you haven't noticed nobody else has been able yet to provide help, this in itself suggests that the problem is not explained well enough_. You cannot expect us to tell your code what the real or false processes are, if you do not tell us that information.

Comment: Yes it does, what you mean is that it does not do what you wanted or expected of it, but then neither did your question, so that seems a fair result.

Comment: I modified the question too many times, to satisfy your requests. I did not expect, that your answer was a low-quality code. Thanks anyway.